# Trigger ngFx animation from the javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angular-directive

I'm trying to use [ngFx library](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ngFx) to play animation when a property changes on the scope. I've created a boilerplate code for directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('zoomInOnChange', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            param: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('param', function () {
                // ?
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and want to use it like this:

```
<h1 zoom-in-on-change param="{{someProp}}">{{someProp}}</h1>
```

Is there a way to trigger ngFx animations from inside the javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, it's way simplier to implement animation working directly with TweenMax, which ngFx uses under the hood. That line of code solved my problem:

```
TweenLite.from(element, 0.5, {scale: 0, ease:Expo.easeIn});
```